# How to capture external attributes on a Doctrine entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship, dql

In my application I have Posts which can be read by Users. I want to capture this state but I'm stuck on how to realize this with an entity structure and relationships.

My idea was to have a User and Post entity and to capture the state of reading to use a PostMeta entity that would look something like this:

```
class PostMeta {
   /** @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id") */
   protected $user;

   /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="meta") */
   protected $post;

   /** @ORM\Column(name="is_read", type="boolean") */
   protected $isRead;
}
```

The PostMeta would always have a OneToOne relationship with a user since it can only ever belong to a single user. It would however, have a ManyToOne relationship with a Post because many users can have PostMeta for the same Post.

To load the actual PostMeta, a Post would have a `$meta` attribute into which the PostMeta can be loaded. Posts are therefore only ever loaded with a specific user in mind:

```
class Post {
   /** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="posts") */
   protected $users;

   /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PostMeta", mappedBy="posts") */
   protected $meta;
}
```

There are two things I'm stuck on:

1. Is this a good approach to solve this problem?
2. How can I write the DQL to retrieve this information keeping in mind that when a user
   hasn't read a Post that there will be no PostMeta entry since PostMeta is only created                 when a User has read a Post.

Comment: The `isRead` field in `PostMeta` seems redundant

Comment: Then where would you suggest I keep track of this state? I might add other states in the future such as starred.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a `ManyToMany` relationship?:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post")
 */
 protected $readPosts;
```

This way you can have the data you need without adding an additional redundant `isRead` field. Of course, this is only valid when you have only one "meta data" to track. The moment you have more you would need to do what are you doing right now, which is basically a manual `ManyToMany` relationship.

To know if a user has read a given post, you can do it directly in your entity:

```
public hasRead(Post $post)
{
    for($this->getReadPosts() as $post)
    {
        if($post === $post)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also, you can use DQL to select which users have read a given post, for example:

```
SELECT u FROM MyBundle:User u JOIN u.readPosts rp WHERE rp = :post
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I can do the same for any other type of attributes. I'm going to give this a try.